# How does google calculate waiting time and receiving time in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How does google calculate waiting time and receiving time in chrome network panel?

There are 4 timing categories in google chrome network panel 
1.) Blocking
2.) Sending
3.) Waiting
4.) Receiving

I would like to know what all factors are included while calculating these options.

From this link

[High "Receiving Time" for HTTP Responses below 500 bytes in Chrome Devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475445/high-receiving-time-for-http-responses-below-500-bytes-in-chrome-devtools)

an explanation is there for receiving, but I would like to know about all the options in a bit more detail. Can anyone please help me out here ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the timing functions may be platform related.

I have an internal web site and the access times reported for the same transactions appear vastly different. For example, my Windows 7 (latest Chrome) shows total response times as 200ms (almost 190ms of receiving) while my Ubuntu laptop shows a total of 4ms on the Chrome Network tab.

I also put timers on my server side first, just to make sure that it was not a delay in my node.js server (running on a different ubuntu box - not the one that has the Chrome client).

Comment: The reason you are seeing ~200ms of receiving time on Windows is probably because of the delayed ACK algorithm.  Here is a page explaining it and how to disable it http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-nagle-algorithm.html